# How to draw sprite according to Player position when button is pressed?

Tags: xna

How do I draw a sprite right at my Player sprite's position when I pressed Spacebar?

```
protected void playerInput() {
        KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape)) this.Exit();
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))     playerPos.Y -= 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))   playerPos.Y += 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))   playerPos.X -= 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))  playerPos.X += 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))  bSpawnSandbag = true;
    }

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
        playerInput();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(player, playerPos, Color.White);

        if (bSpawnSandbag) {
           spriteBatch.Draw(sandbag, new Vector2(playerPos.X + 3, playerPos.Y + 3), Color.White);               
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

If I use the code above, the "sandbag / the sprite I want to draw" will move with my Player position and I don't want that. I want it to draw at THAT specific position my Player was once at when I press Spacebar for 1 time. Any clue? O_O
I want it to be...

Let say, player position = (10, 10) Player pressed Spacebar, draw Sandbag at 10,10 (permanently) Even though Player moved to 12, 10 & not pressing Spacebar , the Sandbag would still be at 10,10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think for a moment what happens if bSpawnSandbag is true. It will always draw the sandbag. However the only input you are using is the playerPos.X/Y for where to draw it. Of course it's going to draw it at the players position. It's continues and not a one time thing. Code isn't called once unless your structure is specified/setup as such. As long the bSpawnSandbag is true, sandbag will be drawn.

I don't know what properties your sprites has. 
Simply keep track of the position when space is hit

```
Vector2 bagPos = new Vector2();

protected void playerInput() {
        KeyboardState key = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape)) this.Exit();
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))     playerPos.Y -= 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))   playerPos.Y += 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))   playerPos.X -= 5;
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))  playerPos.X += 5;

        //If bSpawnSandbag is not true AND spacebar is down
        if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && !bSpawnSandbag)  {

         bSpawnSandbag = true;
         bagPos.X = playerPos.X;
         bagPos.Y = playerPos.Y;

         }
    }

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
        playerInput();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(player, playerPos, Color.White);



        if (bSpawnSandbag) {

           spriteBatch.Draw(sandbag, bagPos, Color.White);               
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

[Here](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/creatinga2dsprite/CreatingA2DSprite.shtml) is a link that might be handy for you. Assuming you are a beginner.

Edit:

As for your question in your comment...

( Not tested and it's just to give you an idea )

Let's assume we are using our own created Sprite class. It contains a Texture2D you need to pass through the constructor and a position vector. Which will be both used in the draw function.

```
public class Sprite(){
public Vector2D position{get;set;}
private Texture2D texture;

public Sprite(Texture2D t, Vector2D pos)
{
  position = pos;
      texture = t;
 }

public Sprite(Texture2D t)
{
    texture = t;
}

public draw(SpriteBatch sb)
{
   sb.draw(texture,position);
}


}
```

Now lets say we have a class that manages our sprites somewhere:

```
//Our list that holds sprite objects
List<Sprite> spriteList = new List<Sprite>();

//Draw all sprites in our list
private void drawSprites(){
  for(int i = 0; i < spriteList.Count; i++)
    //Pass our SpriteBatch to our draw function in Sprite
    spriteList[i].draw(spriteBatch);
}

//Create new sandbags
private void createSandBag(Vector2D atPos){
   Sprite sandbag = new Sprite(MY_STATIC_TEXTURE);
  sandbag = atPos;
  spriteList.add(sandbag);
}
```

you then call createSandBag when Space bar is hit and pass the position of your player

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I asked "when I press Spacebar for 1 time"... I apologize if my question is not clear enough , English is not my native language... Basically, for the Spacebar that part, I want it to be, 

Let say, player position = (10, 10)
Player pressed Spacebar, draw Sandbag at 10,10 (permanently) 
Even though Player moved to 12, 10 & not pressing Spacebar , the Sandbag would still be at 10,10

Comment: @Xeon did you look at the code ? I gave you the solution

Comment: Erm, okay...But if I want to change it to be able to spawn multiple sandbags...Any solution ?

Comment: You are asking for pretty trivial/basic stuff. You should have a function which creates your sandbags and adds them to a list/array and you simply iterate through them with a forloop. Somewhere where you organize your game objects.

Comment: @Xeon added some code

Comment: Oh freaking awesome!!! It works :D Thanks man!
And you're right, I'm new to XNA or C# or OOP languages...Only coded in C before , haven't touched any other languages before.